# How can I kill the Jenkins process?

Tags: macos

I have Jenkins running on my computer and occupying port 8080.

[image]

I'm unable to kill it.

Something like `ps -9 PID` would kill the process, but Jenkins will restart with a different PID.

I thought maybe when Jenkins was started, there was also a user "`jenkins`" created. I searched for that user in "*System Preferences > Users & Groups*" but I couldn't find it.

Any idea how I can terminate Jenkins? Maybe I need to delete the user "jenkins" ?

Comment: Yup, it made the HNQ.  Nice title!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Launch daemons

On macOS, Jenkins runs as a *launch daemon,* or simply *daemon,* which is just a fancy name for a specific way to have a program run in the background. According to Apple’s [developer reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2083/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003794-CH1-SUBSECTION2), a daemon on macOS is:

> [...] a program that runs in the background as part of the overall system (that is, it is not tied to a particular user).

Launch daemons are associated with a macOS-internal process called `launchd`, which runs all the time. One of `launchd`’s various responsibilities is to (re-)launch a daemon whenever it deems it necessary. This also explains the behavior you described that Jenkins seems to respawn on its own after it is forcibly sent the `KILL` signal.

### Stopping and uninstalling Jenkins

There is more than one way to stop a running Jenkins instance. As per the [original documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Thanks+for+using+OSX+Installer) of the Jenkins installer for macOS, the following steps are the recommended way to terminate a Jenkins instance on macOS:

1. Open `Terminal.app` (you did that already; if not, type `terminal` into a Spotlight search field and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
2. If you want to stop Jenkins only once, run the following command:

   ```
   sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
   ```
3. If you would rather uninstall Jenkins altogether, also run the following command (including the single quotes):

   ```
   '/Library/Application Support/Jenkins/Uninstall.command'
   ```